# How do I find and use the filename on photos in Photos.app?

Tags: photos, photos.app

I live by my photo filenames but they are gone in now that there is the new (crappy) Photos. Thankfully on one computer I did not do the update so I still have iPhoto.

Certainly I'm missing something silly and the filenames are still there but I can't locate them in Photos. I appreciate any help.

Comment: and you do mean the file name not the title !

Answer (score 2):

You can still see the original file name of a photo in the information panel, opened using <kbd>cmd ⌘</kbd> <kbd>I</kbd>. It's right there under the photo's title.

It seems you cannot search for file names in the Photos.app search. What still works is creating a *smart album* (<kbd>⌥ alt</kbd> <kbd>cmd ⌘</kbd>  <kbd>N</kbd>) to search for a specific file name or a pattern. See for example [this Macworld article](http://www.macworld.com/article/2925224/smart-uses-for-smart-albums-in-photos-for-mac.html).

The Photos app really hides the actual file names quite well. In the finder, you cannot even search for them using Spotlight unless you first open the package content of your Photos library and directly search in that Finder window.

Comment: You can most definitely search by filename within the Photos app.

Comment: @Phong I can confirm that, seems the function has been restored/fixed.

Answer (score 1):

If you mean the Photograph Titles, that can be toggled by  <kbd>Cmd ⌘</kbd>   <kbd>Shift ⇧</kbd>   <kbd>T</kbd> 
or you can find it in View > Metadata > Titles

Answer (score 0):

And if you are not talking about Titles but the camera assigned file name, then you are out of luck.

The migration from iPhoto to Photo does not migrate the actual file name.

There is a chance to see the file name in the "Moments" view.